# Clickhouse cannot start normally after migrating the data directory

Tags: clickhouse

By modifying the data directory in the <tmp_path><ebs_gp2_1><format_schema_paht> tag in the config.xml file of clickhouse, from /data/appData/clickhouse to /vdata/tg-paas/data/clickhouse directory.
[image]
[image]

After completing the modification, I restarted clickhouse, but it failed to start.
The follow is error info.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought it was because I had a problem with the configuration of config.xml, so I checked many times, and checked with our senior operation and maintenance personnel, and found that there is no problem with the configuration file of config.xml. Finally, I managed to solve this problem by the following method.

(1) Copy all files under /data/appData/clickhouse to /vdata/tg-paas/data/clickhouse

(2) Modify the owner of /vdata/tg-paas/data/clickhouse to be consistent with /data/appData/clickhouse.